# When will the launch celebration end?

Tags: hearthstone

When waiting for an opponent in an tavern brawl there is sometimes this text displayed:

[image]

> 'Win a classic pack every week in Tavern Brawl during the launch celebration!'

Do we know when the launch celebration is going to end? Will it ever end?

Comment: Probably never.. haven't seen a blue post about this and it's been over a year now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it was intended as a launch promo but has simply never ended.  I don't think there's been any official word on this, it's just been kind of left unsaid.

Given we're over a year of tavern brawls now it's probably safe to assume it's permanent.

Comment: To add to this; There was a huge fuss on the forums with people complaining about losing their primary way of getting classic packs, after they changed the arena reward packs to be from the most recent expansion, instead of the classic packs. Blizzards decision for the "seemingly infinite launch celebration" might have been influenced by this.

Comment: Blizzard experimented with not giving a pack during the December holidays (they gave a holiday card back instead of a pack) and there was a lot of outrage.  I suspect that was dipping their toe in the water and they decided it wasn't worth moving forward in that direction.